# ViewModel many to many relationship

Tags: c#, generics, viewmodel

For our project, we would like to use ViewModels.
So we decided to create ViewModels for every object we can have :

So the ViewModel looks like this (GroupVM) :

```
public class GroupVM : EORTCViewModel<Prisma.BO.Group>
{
    public GroupVM(Prisma.BO.Group group) : base(group) { }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Model.Name;
        }
    }
    public string ShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Model.ShortName;
        }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Model.Id;
        }
    }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public ICollection<StudyGroupVM> StudyGroups
    {
        get
        {
            return Prisma.Web.Models.Factories.ViewModelFactory<Prisma.BO.StudyGroup>.ToViewModel<StudyGroupVM>(this._Model.StudyGroups);
        }
    }
}
```

The StudyVM :

```
public class StudyVM : EORTCViewModel<Prisma.BO.Study>
{
    public StudyVM(Prisma.BO.Study study) : base(study) { }

    public string Number
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Model.Number;
        }
    }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public ICollection<StudyGroupVM> StudyGroups
    {
        get
        {
            return Prisma.Web.Models.Factories.ViewModelFactory<Prisma.BO.StudyGroup>.ToViewModel<StudyGroupVM>(this._Model.StudyGroups);
        }
    }
}
```

and the intermediate object (StudyGroup) :

```
public class StudyGroupVM : EORTCViewModel<Prisma.BO.StudyGroup>
{
    public StudyGroupVM(Prisma.BO.StudyGroup studyGroup) : base(studyGroup) { }

    public StudyVM Study
    {
        get
        {
            return Prisma.Web.Models.Factories.ViewModelFactory<Prisma.BO.Study>.ToViewModel<StudyVM>(this._Model.Study);
        }
    }

    public GroupVM Group
    {
        get
        {
            return Prisma.Web.Models.Factories.ViewModelFactory<Prisma.BO.Group>.ToViewModel<GroupVM>(this._Model.Group);
        }
    }
}
```

We would like to use a factory that would create ViewModels for every navigation properties.

So we wrote a generic ViewModel factory as follow :

```
public static class ViewModelFactory<T> where T : IEORTCObject
{
    public static R ToViewModel<R>(T model) where R : EORTCViewModel<T>
    {
        return (R)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(R), new object[] { model });
    }

    public static ICollection<R> ToViewModel<R>(ICollection<T> models) where R : EORTCViewModel<T>
    {
        ICollection<R> viewModels = new List<R>();
        foreach (T model in models)
        {
            viewModels.Add((R)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(R), new object[] { model }));
        }
        return viewModels;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when we try to access the StudyGroups property from one of the end object of the relation, it creates correctly the object but then want to recreate the same object because it seems it tries to access the getter for the other end of the relation.

This cause a StackOverFlowException since it never stops (cycles).

Does any of you have any idea how I can solve this issue ?

Comment: all I can say is that Activator.CreateInstance is not a good IOC-container!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use memoization to cache your viemodel after it has been created once?

Something like:

```
public GroupVM Group
{
    get
    {
       if(groupVM == null)
       {
             groupVM = Prisma.Web.Models.Factories.ViewModelFactory<Prisma.BO.Group>.ToViewModel<GroupVM>(this._Model.Group);
        }
        return groupVM;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then I would need a container that will hold references of every viewModels that has already been created. But indeed, I could do that.

Comment: Any other idea since if we use this, we will need to have lots of checks to know when create new instance or not since the complete model is pretty big.

Comment: Why do you need to use view models at all?

Comment: Since we are using Telerik MVC Extension GridView, and those need JSON to work properly with ajax binding, we would like to be able to convert the BO to JSON. And the JSON serializer throw some exceptions when trying to convert the BOs. But I'm open to every other possibilities of course.

Comment: You could try to use something like AutoMapper to create your ViewModels. It may handle your circular refernces but I haven't used it for quite a few years